# Does Windows 10 support the AAC codec over A2DP for Bluetooth headphones when installed on a Mac via Bootcamp?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, audio, bluetooth, headphones

Unlike MacOS, Windows 10 itself does not support the AAC codec for the A2DP profile for Bluetooth headphones; only the SBC codec. However, when installing Windows 10 on a Mac via Bootcamp, lots of drivers are installed to make Windows run smooth on the Mac. Will this enable the AAC codec as well?

Comment: Would this not depend on which model Mac you wish to install Windows on?

Comment: Why would it? In my case it’s a MacBook Air 2014.

Comment: The hardware often varies between different Mac models. Each model has one or more sets of available boot camp drivers you can download. There is no universal set of drivers that can be download that work with all Macs. Why not just install Windows and find out.

Comment: Of course are the drivers different, but I doubt that the decision of wether or not to include the AAC codec for Bluetooth is done anew for every model. Thus, if someone can confirm that they have AAC on a different model, I’d be fairly confident to find it in my model too.

Comment: I have a 2013 iMac and 2018 mac mini with Windows 10 installed. Is there a place to look or does it require a Bluetooth device that uses a AAC codec in order to verify?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that easy. Yes, you’d need a Bluetooth headphone with AAC, like AirPods. But then you’d need a program to log the Bluetooth connection and find the codec that’s been used in the log.

Comment: This blog explains how to do it: https://helgeklein.com/blog/2020/09/how-to-check-which-bluetooth-a2dp-audio-codec-is-used-on-windows/